# How to Save settings of custom tab product page in admin side in a database?

Tags: plugins, posts, custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic

[image]

I have following code :

```
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php _e('Custom Stock Message'); ?></th>
                             <td>
                                <input type="text" name="customstock-msg"  value=""/>
                             </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th><?php _e('Order Processing Time'); ?></th>
                             <td>

                               <input type="text" name="customstock-Processing-time">
                             </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th><?php _e('Instock Date'); ?></th>
                             <td>
                               <!-- <input type="date" name="customstock-date"  value=""/>-->
                               <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="customstock-instockdate">
                             </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th><?php _e('Show Quantity when Instock'); ?></th>
                             <td>
                               <!-- <input type="date" name="customstock-date"  value=""/>-->
                               <select name="customstock-quantity" id="showquantity">
                                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                                    <option value="no"> No</option>
                               </select>
                             </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th><?php _e('Show on Catlog Page'); ?></th>
                             <td>
                               <!-- <input type="date" name="customstock-date"  value=""/>-->
                               <select name="customstock-catlogpage" id="showcatlogpage">
                                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                                    <option value="no"> No</option>
                               </select>
                             </td>
                    </tr>

                    ?>

                     <p>
                     <input type="submit" class="button-primary" name="customstock_submit_specific_product" value="<?php  _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
                     </p>
                  </form>

  if(isset($_POST['customstock_submit_specific_product']))
 {
                    global $wpdb,$product;
                     $id = $product->id;

                    $custommsg = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['customstock-msg'] );
                    $customprocessingtime = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['customstock-Processing-time'] );
                    $customstockquantity = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['customstock-quantity'] );
                    $customstockcatlogpage = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['customstock-catlogpage'] );
                    $customstockinstockdate = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['customstock-instockdate'] );
                    $customstockinstockdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($customstockinstockdate) );

  $wpdb->insert('wp_woocommerce_specific_product_settings', array(
                                                                    'custom_msg' => $custommsg,
                                                                    'order_processing_time'  => $customprocessingtime,
                                                                    'exp_instock_date' => $customstockinstockdate, 
                                                                'show_stockstatus_quantity' => $customstockquantity,
                                                                    'showon_catlog' => $customstockcatlogpage,
                                                                    'specific_product_id' =>  $id
                                                                ));
  }
```

Above code is ececuted when submit button is press.
I don't want to store in wp_postmeta then what to do.I am beginner in a wordpress.Anyone have idea how I can save it?

Comment: Why you do not want to save in post meta ? Also please format your code!

Comment: I easily identify store value and retrieve easily so i want to store in another table and retrieve easily.

Comment: The most easiest way is going in WordPress way. If you still want to with custom table then please show your code where you've implemented custom query.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your situation I don't recommend or condone doing this, but the answer to your question is to take a look at the `$wpdb` class and the `dbDelta()` function. This is the interface WordPress provides for adding custom tables.

Be careful though, with great power comes great responsibility. Using `$wpdb` bypasses many of the built-in WordPress security features, so you need to be **very** cautious with sanitizing and escaping data to avoid introducing SQL injection vulnerabilities and other security holes.

That said, here's an abstracted class I recently used to do this for a client that may be useful for you to work with. I didn't test this, it's an abstraction from a much larger class so you'll need to re-configure and test it yourself. For what it's worth, I don't think you need a custom table for this use case.

```
<?php
/**
 * Database
 *
 * Add custom tables to a WordPress database
 */

if ( ! class_exists('DB_Table') ) :

class DB_Table 
{
    protected $table;

    /**
     * Create Database Table
     *
     * Given a schema array, create a custom table in the WP database
     */
    public static function create() {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );

        global $wpdb, $charset_collate;

        $table = 'custom_table_name'; // The name of your custom DB table
        $schema = self::schema();

        // create database table
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . $table;
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name ( ";
        $sql .= $schema;
        $sql .= " ) $charset_collate;";

        // run create process
        dbDelta( $sql );
    }

    /**
     * Schema: Level Term Rates 
     *
     * Schema definition for the custom table
     */
    public static function schema() {

        // Define your schema here for the table
        $schema = "id int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        age int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        first_name text NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        last_name text NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        gender char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        PRIMARY KEY (id)";

        return $schema;
    }
}

/**
 * Register Hooks
 */
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'DB_Table', 'create' ) );

endif;
?>
```

Comment: I don't want to make table But I want to store value in table that's not working @kevin Leary.

Comment: I can do nothing for you.